# Limit as n goes to infinity of $(1+n)^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $(1+n)^{1/n}$

I was able to determine that this was always approaching $1$ but I didn't know how to prove that it was equal to $e$.

Comment: What do you mean? The limit is 1, so what does it have to do with $e$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the sandwhich theorem and 
$$\sqrt[n]{1} \leq \sqrt[n]{1+n} \leq \sqrt[n]{2n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that,

> $$ (1+n)^{1/n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+n)}. $$

Now, take the limit and you can use L'hopital's rule. The limit should be $1$.

**Note:**

> $$\lim e^{a_n} = e^{\lim a_n}$$

due to the continuity of the exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1 + n}^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}n^{1/n}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}n^{1/n}\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{1/n}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over \left(1/n\right)^{1/n}}
= \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}{1 \over x^{x}}} = 1$